# Number of days = 3 then put an X in every cell from start to end date

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have one cell that specifies the number of days a person is reserving a room. And I want excel to put a X below a row of dates, like this.

```
Row 1: Persons name - start date - Check out date - 01-01-2013 - 02-01-2013 - 03-01-2013

Row 2: Michel        01-01-2013       02-01-2013   (Make X here)  (And here)
```

Is this doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(The below is assuming `Persons name` is in cell A1)*

1. In cell `D2` (the first cell an "X" can appear), enter the formula: `=IF(AND($B2<=D$1,$C2>=D$1),"X","")`
2. Drag the formula in `D2` all the way to the right as far as you need, i.e. under each date
3. Now drag this formula down, against as many rows as you need, i.e. the number of people checking in (every cell that can potentially have "X" should have the formula from step 1.)

In the above, I am simply checking in each cell whether the date of that column falls between the `Start date` and `Check out date` (both dates inclusive). If true, then mark an "X" in that cell.

Comment: It gives me a error at the , between D1 and c2 =IF(AND($B2<=D$1,$C2>=D$1),"X","")

Comment: What is the error? What does the cell say?

Comment: I got it to work! THANKS ALOT! can i give you some kind of points for the solution or? :-)

Comment: i had to replace , with ; thats all :-)

Comment: Great :) What was the issue? I'd like to fix anything I may have missed while writing my answer. You can accept my answer as the correct one by clicking the check mark on the left of my answer.

Comment: Ah ok, you must be on a different locale, as my Excel uses commas not semi-colons :)